# My scapy sniffer does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a program that collects data from packets in iterations. Until a couple of days ago it worked fine.
EDIT: SOLVED. I saved IP as a constant and it overwrote IP.

```
from scapy.all import * 
import requests
import socket



ROUND = 2
IP = 'localhost'
PORT = 80
SERVER_ADDRESS = (IP,PORT)








def get_packet_size(packet):
    return len(packet)


def find_port(packet,ip):

    if packet[IP].dst == ip:
        if TCP in packet:
            return packet[TCP].sport
        else:
            return packet[UDP].sport
    else:
        if UDP in packet:
            return packet[TCP].dport
        else:
            return packet[UDP].dport
def check_traffic(packet , ip):

    if packet[IP].dst == ip:
        return False
    else:
        return True
def find_country(packet, ip):
    request = "http://freegeoip.net/json/"+ip
    response = requests.get(request)
    real_response = response.text

    real_response = real_response.split(",")
    country_full = real_response[2]
    country_full = country_full.split(":")
    country = country_full[1]
    country = country[1:len(country) - 1]
    print(country)

    return str(country)


def find_ip(packet):
    name = socket.gethostname()
    ip_of_agent = socket.gethostbyname(name)

    if(packet[IP].dst != ip_of_agent):
        return packet[IP].dst
    else:
        return packet[IP].src

def work_on_packets(packets):
    packet_dic = {}
    #ip_dic = []
    i = 0 # num of packet in iteration.
    for packet in packets:

        print("\n")
        packet_ip = find_ip(packet)
        print(packet_ip)

        country = find_country(packet,packet_ip)
        print(country)

        is_coming_traffic = check_traffic(packet,packet_ip) # True if coming , False if outer traffic. 

        port = find_port(packet,packet_ip)
        print(port)

        packet_size = get_packet_size(packet)
        print(packet_size)

        packet_dic["Packet "+str(i)] = [packet_ip,country,is_coming_traffic,port,packet_size]
        i = i + 1

    #send_data(packet_dic)





def is_IP(packet):
    return ((UDP in packet or TCP in packet) and IP in packet)

def main():
    print("Starting sniff..")
    while(True):
        packets = sniff(lfilter = is_IP )
        work_on_packets(packets)



main()
```

But right now it just doesn't work. The output is always like this,nothing more:

```
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?). This affects only IPv6
Starting sniff..
```

What could be the problem behind it? any help is great!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning telling you that you don;t have any default routes for IPV6 and is totally normal for systems that do not have IPV6. This should not affect your program for IPV4 packets.

Here's how you can disable it

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem. I was saving 'local host' as const instead of IP and it overwrote.